# C# primitive silent overflow - CLR via c#

Tags: c#, .net, byte

I'm reading CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter and on page 115 there is an example of an overflow resulting from arithmetic operations on primitives. Can someone pls explain?

```
Byte b = 100;
b = (Byte) (b+200); // b now contains 44 (or 2C in Hex).
```

I understand that there should be an overflow, since `byte` is an unsigned 8-bit value, but why does its value equal 44?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

100+200 is 300; 300 is (in bits):

```
1 0010 1100
```

Of this, only the last 8 is kept, so:

```
0010 1100
```

which is: 44

Comment: great explanation using bits :) (+1) from me.

Answer (score 0):

A `byte` can hold represent integers in the range between 0 and 255 (inclusive). When you pass a value greater than the 255, like 300, the value of 300-256=44 is stored. This happens because a byte is consisted of 8 bits and each bit can either 0 or 1. So you can represent 2^8=256 integers using a byte, starting from 0.

Actually, you have to divide your number with the 256. The remainder of this can only be represented by a byte.

Answer (score 0):

The binary representation of 300 is `100101100`. That's nine bits, one more than the `byte` type has room for. Therefore the higher bit is discarded, causing the result to be `00101100`. When you translate this value to decimal you get 44.